# Lodash template engine Nashorn

Tags: java, lodash, nashorn

I'm currently trying to use the lodash template engine in Java using nashorn and I'm facing an issue.

Here's the code :

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine nashorn = mgr.getEngineByName("nashorn");
ScriptContext ctx = nashorn.getContext();
Bindings bindings = ctx.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
nashorn.eval(readFileToString("externallibs/lodash.min.js"), bindings);
String tpl = readFileToString("hello.tpl");
bindings.put("tpl", tpl);
nashorn.eval("compiled = _.template(tpl);", bindings);
ScriptObjectMirror compiled = (ScriptObjectMirror)nashorn.get("compiled");
System.out.println("compiled = " + compiled);
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String(1);
props.put("name", "world");
bindings.put("props", props);
System.out.println(compiled.call(this, bindings.get("props"));
```

The template is well compiled by Nashorn, if you look at the console you'll see :

```
compiled = function(obj){obj||(obj={});var __t,__p='';with(obj){__p+='Hello, '+((__t=( name ))==null?'':__t);}return __p}
```

But when I'm trying to call the compiled template function above with a map as parameter (the props), as you would do in JS : 

`tpl.call(this, {name:'world'})`

It fails with the following error :

`TypeError: Cannot apply "with" to non script object`

And indeed, we can see that the compiled version of the function uses the 'with' keyword.

Does anyone have an idea on how to workaround this issue ? How should I send the parameters to render the compiled template ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a JS script object to "with" statement. Arbitrary Java object (which is not a JS object - say a java.util.Vector or object of your class Foo) can not be used as "with" expression. You could create an empty script using code like

```
Object emptyScriptObj = engine.eval("({})");
```

and pass emptyScriptObj to your ScriptObjectMirror.call method call for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out this was the cause of the failure. But I can't find a proper solution to inject my Java HashMap (props) as a ScriptEngineMirror object. Do you have an idea ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To use a Java map as scope expression for "with" statement, you could use something like this:

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
      Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("foo", 34);
      map.put("bar", "hello");

      ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");
      // expose 'map' as a variable
      e.put("map", map);

      // wrap 'map' as a script object
      // __noSuchProperty__ hook is called to look for missing property
      // missing property is searched in the map
      e.eval("obj = { __noSuchProperty__: function(name) map.get(name) }");

      // use that wrapper as scope expression for 'with' statement
      // prints 34 and hello from the map
      e.eval("with (obj) { print(foo); print(bar); }");
   }
}
```

Comment: I think a brace is missing if I'm not mistaking. But I'll give this solution a try. Thanks a lot for your answer.